# Extract part of a div attribute from html page

Tags: php, html

I have this part of an html page:

```
<td>
  <div class='medals gold'> 
    </div> 
</td>
```

To extract and print to video the div attribute I used this php code:

```
$div = $result->getElementByTagName('div');
echo $div->getAttribute('class') . " ";
```

In this way I get the string `medals gold`.

Could I extract indeed only the substring `gold`?
It would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string `medals gold` into an array of two strings `array('medals', 'gold')`:

```
$div = $result->getElementByTagName('div');
$parts = explode(' ', $div->getAttribute('class'));
echo $parts[1];
```

Comment: `split` function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: updated the answer to something that actually works. Sorry about that.

Comment: I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 1):

You could use preg_split and split the string on the empty space as others suggest

```
/* it should be `getElementsByTagName`*/
$div=$result->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);

list( $junk, $keep )=preg_split('@\s@',$div->getAttribute('class') );
echo $keep;

/* or */
$divs=$result->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach( $divs as $div ){
    list( $junk, $keep )=preg_split('@\s@', $div->getAttribute('class') );
    echo $keep;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `split` function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3, and it is also REMOVED in PHP 7.0, so I would suggest you to use `explode`.

Also

- `explode()` is substantially faster because it doesn't split based on a regular expression, so the string doesn't have to be analyzed by the regex parser
- `preg_split()` is faster and uses PCRE regular expressions for regex splits

So, it would be better option :

```
$div = $result->getElementByTagName('div');
$parts = explode(' ', $div->getAttribute('class'));
echo $parts[1];
```

where you'll get array with 2 strings. `//array('medals', 'gold')`